# Android Standard UI development for hdpi

Tags: android, android-layout

I am relatively new to android. I want to develop an UI which works fine on 2 hpdi devices.
For example lets say on these two devices

**Nexus 9**

1. Size 8.86"
2. Resolution 2560x1600
3. Density xhdpi

**Nexus 10**

1. Size 10.05"
2. Resolution 2560x1600
3. Density xhdpi

As seen above both have different screen size and different resolution but density is the same.
My understanding is one layout should work perfectly on both devices, but unfortunately that is not the case. I see differences. Can someone please suggest what changes i should make.

Adding below the portion of the code(xml) which is giving me a problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.2" >

                                <customSeekBar
                                    android:id="@+id/abc1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                    android:thumb="@drawable/eqthumb"
                                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_eq"
                                    android:max="19"
                                    android:progress="10" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/abc2 "
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ abc1"
                                    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:text="300"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/abc3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/ abc1"
                                    android:text="0 dB"
                                    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what differences are you experiencing?

Comment: @BobMalooga I have edited my question. On my emulator one layout works fine for both. But i notice on physical device the UI is distorted on the smaller screen.

Comment: @Pooya basically the size of particular elements. If i have the size as 280dp. It looks fine on the 10 in screen but on the 8 inch screen the element is chopped off by other neighboring elements. And its not displayed correctly.

Comment: can you show your xml?

Comment: Note: Your device data is off. Nexus 9 is 2048 x 1536 pixels and has an aspect ratio that's 4:3 mind you, compared to 16:10 for the Nexus 10. Both fall in the xhdpi bucket though for resource qualifiers etc. Physical screen density is 288 for the Nexus 9 and 300 for Nexus 10.

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander How do i design android layout in this scenario, in such a way that it works on both the devices

Comment: That's a longer answer, made it into an answer instead of comment.

Comment: @Pooya i have added the xml code portion which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As seen above both have different screen size and different resolution but density is the same. My understanding is one layout should work perfectly on both devices

That's not true, you are building on top of this wrong premise. Simply put:

- > Devices with different screen sizes, but same density, will always work with the same layout

  **False**: different screen sizes (in inches) mean you probably will have to adjust your views. So, provide different layouts, or at least different dimensions.
- > Devices with different densities, but similar screen sizes, should always work with the same layout

  **True**: if the screen size is the same, a `40dp` button will cover the same portion of screen in both devices. That's because `dp`s are *density independent* pixels, and allow us to work on all densities out there with a single value.

I suggest you read this [official resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), that should clear your mind. In the very first bullet list, we read:

> - Provide different **layouts** for different **screen sizes**
> - Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

As you can see, there's no `Provide different layouts for different screen densities`, which was the premise of your question. That's just something you don't do usually, it makes no sense if you use (and understand) `dp`s.

Comment: @m vai I understand what you said. But this brings out another concern. When we design different layouts my understanding from tutorials is that we have to define "layout-hdpi", "layout-xhdpi", "layout-xxhdpi" etc. Are these not referring to densities and not screen sizes? So if I want to support different screens does it mean i should create 1 layout for 8 inch screen, one for 9 inch screen etc? Also how do I place it in the folder structure so that android picks the right layout.

Comment: I have never seen `layout-xhdpi` folders. Yes, you can use them, but practically I have never seen them used. Just use `layout`. About screen sizes, usually it's enough to use just two version of a layout, one for smaller screens (e.g. smartphones) and one for bigger ones (e.g. tablets). These can be distinguished, for example, with the `sw` qualifier - see table 2 [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). The folder `layout-sw600dp` will be accessed for devices that have width >= 600dp (approx. 7" tablets).

Answer (score 2):

Density is only one part of your layouts though. These devices have different aspect ratios so available device independent pixel (dip or just dp) differs.

So your available width and height differs, but sure logical screen density is the same.

Having said that, android's layouts are rather flexible/adaptable and regardless of screen density. ***Your layout might need to compensate for different widths or heights though.*** Just as it might want/need to change due to portrait or landscape mode, different aspect ratios (a potential issue with these two devices) has the same difference.

So you are incorrect in assuming that your layout differs a lot due to hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi etc. You might want to qualify your layouts on available screen width or similar (sw720dp for example) instead if needed.

- Nexus 9 has a logical screen density of: 1024 x 768 dip
- Nexus 10 has a logical screen density of: 1280 x 800 dip

*Having said that, your particular layout issue needs your specific xml layouts to be explained.* For many layouts those two devices should be able to look the same.

Note: Your device data is off. Nexus 9 is 2048 x 1536 pixels and has an aspect ratio that's 4:3 mind you, compared to 16:10 for the Nexus 10. Both fall in the xhdpi bucket though for resource qualifiers etc. Physical screen density is 288 for the Nexus 9 and 300 for Nexus 10.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Having said this, does it mean i should create different layouts for different aspect ratios. Also i have a limitation that i have only emulator no physical device for constant tetsing. On the emulator this layout looks fine on both devices. Physical devices gives a problem. Could you please suggest how to approach this?

Comment: The emulator and physical device shouldn't differ. It's still unclear what layout issue you are having though. Your added xml is great, but what is the issue exactly? Is that the entire layout, the use of layout_weight suggests it's wrapped in a LinearLayout?